# Always getting Run Time Error in Google Code jam

Tags: python, runtime-error

I wrote my code in python-3 in google Code jam unfortunately,I am always getting Run time Error , though the code it correct and is getting executed in jupyter notebook.

[I already found one answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023575/always-getting-runtime-error-google-code-jam)  but I am not clear with the solution on how to implement it, so can someone please give me solution for this problem .

Here is my code-

```
import numpy as np
n = int(input())
a = []
b = []
t = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))
    for j in range(a[-1]):
        t.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

        b += t
        t = []
    x = a[0]
    k = 0


def cal(temp):
    row = 0
    k = 1
    for i in temp:
        dict = {}
        flag = 0
        for j in i:
            if j not in dict.keys():
                dict[j] = 1
                flag = 0

            else:
                flag = 1
                break

        if flag == 1:
            row += k
    return row


def func(temp):
    temp = np.array(temp)
    t = 0
    row = cal(temp)
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        t += temp[i][i]

    col = cal(temp.T)
    return t, row, col


for i in range(n):
    q = func(b[k:x])

    d = i + 1
    print("Case #{}: {} {} {}".format(d, q[0],q[1],q[2]))

    k = x
    x += a[i]
```

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: python 3 @RajuKomati, I don't know the exact version which is being used by the Google Code jam

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can't figure out your problem if you don't show your work. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: If you use f strings it wont work

Comment: @stephenwade I am sorry , I forgot about uploading the code , but I uploaded code please go through my work give me  a solution

Comment: @ThunderHorn I followed the method mentioned in Google FAQs'  for std output in python 3

Comment: @noob_Coder is problem wit accepting inputs? or the overall code

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` and other external libraries are not available. Also `f strings` do not work as mentioned.

Also throughout your whole code, you did not use any numpy functions anyways, so just replace it with a normal python `list` and it should work fine.

Good luck in GCJ~

Comment: Thanks for the information about the external libraries , but for std output I followed Google FAQs' method but still, I am getting Run Time Error

Comment: What do you mean? Can you post your updated code after removing numpy and f strings? Also, for which problem is the code for? Thank you @noob_Coder

Answer (score 0):

Helper function for the inputs I wont give you any logic but this will help you work with the google Judge system

```
def solve(matrix, size):
   return "{} {} {}".format(a, b, c)

for T in range(1, int(input()) + 1):
    size = int(input())
    matrix = [input().split(' ') for i in range(size)]
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(T, solve(matrix, size)))
```